# Creating Rails todo list app with goals and tasks on one page - missing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a Rails beginner, and have been reading tutorials and typing out applications for a few months now. I'm really enjoying it after a few years spent in the front end world, and beginning to get up to speed with it all. The time has come though for me to start building my own stuff without any handholding. So far, so good.

I'm creating a basic to-do list app, where goals and tasks are displayed on the **same** page - goals#index. My issue is that I'm not sure how to get all tasks for a particular goal (that belongs to a user). I understand that I need to pass an ID param to the Goal model in order to find out its tasks, like so:

```
Goal.find(1).tasks
```

The above works fine, as I've already set up foreign keys on the tasks table and have a has_many :tasks relationship for the Goal model and a belongs_to relationship for the Task model.

Here's my Goals controller:

```
  def index
  @user = current_user

  @goals = @user.goals # list all goals for the current user and assign it to the @goals variable.

  # Need to find all tasks for each goal ID and assign it to the @tasks variable. Goal ID needs to      be supplied here, but it isn't as we're not in show action.
  @tasks = Goal.find(1).tasks
```

As I said, I can find all tasks for a Goal when I manually enter the ID (1 in this example). This works fine in my app, no errors. But obviously I want to supply these IDs dynamically, and I'm just not sure how I get the params in there.

I have tried the below:

```
@tasks = Goal.find(params[:id]).tasks
```

and

```
@tasks = Goal.find(params[:goal_id]).tasks
```

And I get the "Couldn't find Goal without an ID" error when I try to iterate over @tasks in my view. Which makes sense, as I don't think the goal params are being passed to it as we're not in the Show action.

Surely there must be an easy Rails way?! I'm stumped and don't really know where to look. Thanks for your help and Happy New Year.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting current user's goals, so when you will do this you have one array object. so when you will pass array object to find, it will have multiple IDS. so when need to find All the tasks from all goals you just need to pass Array of IDS instead of single value.

```
@tasks = Task.where(:goal_id => @goals)
```

This will run this SQL query.

> SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."goal_id" IN (SELECT
>   "goals"."id" FROM "goals")

So when you are dealing with array just pass ids. for e.g. [1,2,3]

Answer (score 2):

Once you do `@goals = @user.goals` (assuming that's working, which it sounds like it is), you have your goals and there is no reason to go back to the DB to "find" them.

To get ALL your tasks from ALL of user's goals, you can do the following:

```
@tasks = []
@goals.each do |goal|
  @tasks << goal.tasks
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah of course, @goals is an array of the user's goals so I can just work with that. So simple when someone just tells you. Thanks for all your help!

Here's my final code that works (I left the controller unchanged). This gets the first goal in the array and then gets the tasks associated with each goal. I have a set number of goals so I can just use goals[0], goals[1] or goals[2] for each goal.

```
<% @goals[0].tasks.each do |task| %>
  <li><div class="task-item"><%= task.task_name %></div></li>
<% end %>
```